# How can I center svg-text(inside the clipPath tag) to clip the video?

Tags: html, svg

I need to create a text that video can play inside the area,

here is my code :

```
<video src="./my-video.mp4"
                    loop mute autoplay style="clip-path:url(#clipText)"></video>
   <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 479.8 104" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <defs>
                        <clipPath id="clipText">
                            <text x="28" y="15" dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="central">
                                <tspan>FUTURE OF THE
                                    CITY</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </clipPath>
                    </defs>

   </svg>
```

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Actually, I can center it, but I can't make it responsive.

Comment: text-anchor="middle" is the correct syntax